# BCNF Decompositions and Lossless joins for Databases

Tags: database, database-design, functional-dependencies, bcnf

Hey all I have an assignment that says:

Let R(ABCD) be a relation with functional dependencies
A → B, C → D, AD → C, BC → A
Which of the following is a lossless-join decomposition of R into Boyce-Codd Normal Form (BCNF)?

I have been researching and watching videos on youtube and I cannot seem to find how to start this. I think I'm supposed to break it down to subschemas and then fill out a table to find which one is lossless, but I'm having trouble getting started with that. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you google BCNF decomposition there are lots of university slides online. There are also a number of database textbooks online. Your question is essentially asking that section of a book.

Answer (score 12):

Your question

> Which of the following is a lossless-join decomposition of R into
>   Boyce-Codd Normal Form (BCNF)?

suggests that you have a set of options and you have to choose which one of those is a lossless decomposition but since you have not mentioned the options I would first (**PART A**) decompose the relation into BCNF ( first to 3NF then BCNF ) and then (**PART B**) illustrate how to check whether this given decomposition is a lossless-join decomposition or not. If you are just interested in knowing how to check whether a given BCNF decomposition is lossless or not jump directly to PART B of my answer.

**PART A**

To convert a relation `R` and a set of functional dependencies(`FD's`) into `3NF` you can use ***Bernstein's Synthesis***. To apply Bernstein's Synthesis -

- **First** we make sure the given set of `FD's` is a **minimal cover**
- **Second** we take each `FD` and make it its own sub-schema.
- **Third** we try to combine those sub-schemas

***For example*** in your case:

R = {A,B,C,D}
FD's = {A->B,C->D,AD->C,BC->A}

**First** we check whether the `FD's` is a minimal cover (*singleton right-hand side , no extraneous left-hand side attribute, no redundant FD*)

- *Singleton RHS:* All the given FD's already have singleton RHS.
- *No extraneous LHS attribute:* None of the FD's have extraneous LHS attribute that needs to e removed.
- *No redundant FD's:* There is no redundant FD.

Hence the given set of FD's is already a minimal cover.

**Second** we make each `FD` its own sub-schema. So now we have -  (*the keys for each relation are in bold*)

R<sub>1</sub>={**A,D**,C}
R<sub>2</sub>={**B,C**,A}
R<sub>3</sub>={**C**,D}
R<sub>4</sub>={**A**,B}

**Third** we see if any of the sub-schemas can be combined. We see that **R<sub>1</sub>** and **R<sub>2</sub>** already have all the attributes of `R` and hence R<sub>3</sub> and R<sub>4</sub> can be omitted. So now we have -

S<sub>1</sub> = {A,D,C}
S<sub>2</sub> = {B,C,A}

This is in **3NF**. Now to check for **BCNF** we check if any of these relations (S<sub>1</sub>,S<sub>2</sub>) violate the conditions of **BCNF** (*i.e. for **every** functional dependency `X->Y` the left hand side (`X`) **has to be** a **superkey***) . In this case none of these violate **BCNF** and hence it is also decomposed to **BCNF**.

**PART B**

When you apply Bernstein Synthesis as above to decompose `R` the decomposition is always dependency preserving. Now the question is, is the decomposition lossless? To check that we can follow the following method :

Create a table as shown in figure 1, with number of rows equal to the number of decomposed relations and number of column equal to the number of attributes in our original given `R`.

[image]

We put ***a*** in all the attributes that our present in the respective decomposed relation as in figure 1. Now we go through all the FD's {C->D,A->B,AD->C,BC->A} one by one and add ***a*** whenever possible. For example, first FD is C->D. Since both the rows in column C has ***a*** and there is an empty slot in second row of column D we put a ***a*** there as shown in the right part of the image. We stop as soon as one of the rows is completely filled with ***a*** which indicates that it is a lossless decomposition. If we go through all the FD's and none of the rows of our table get completely filled with ***a*** then it is a lossy decomposition.

*Also, note if it is a lossy decomposition we can always make it lossless by adding one more relation to our set of decomposed relations consisting of all attributes of the primary key.*

I suggest you see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQ3ME7oOupU) video for more examples of this method. Also [other way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300853/lossless-join-decomposition?rq=1) to check for lossless join decomposition which involves relational algebra.